# Can't open phpmyadmin, require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I do `php /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php`, I get this.

> PHP Warning:  require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php on line 33
>   PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './libraries/common.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php on line 33

The `common.inc.php` file seems to be there.

I didn't make any changes and hadn't used phpmyadmin in a while.

---

Update: Here is a search:

```
# find / -name "common.inc.php" -print
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib/common.inc.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php
```

index.php is at `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php`, so this looks right to me.

Comment: File, you want to include, doesn´t exists, or is in another location.

Answer (score 1):

`cd /usr/share/php mv php-gettext php-gettext.orig && ln -s php-php-gettext php-gettext`

works for me. on Debian 4.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the directory `./libraries/` in the PhpMyAdmin base directory. And see if the file `common.inc.php` is there or not. It is mandatory that the file should be there not anywhere else. You already said that it's there. But please check if that's in the right directory.

If nothing fixes the issue then try RE-INSTALLING PhpMyAdmin... I will suggest you take a BACKUP of your DATABASES first.

Comment: I've updated the OP with the location of that file. It looks right. I guess I will try reinstalling anyhow.

Comment: Reinstalling and purging (both using apt-get and by using the purge option at uninstall prompt) don't fix it. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had some other errors with mysql that I thought were unrelated. This is the message I got repeatedly every second for about a minute whenever I started or stopped mysqld:

`2014-11-23 12:27:42 871 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
2014-11-23 12:27:42 871 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.`

I followed this post to fix them (copied below): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24840903/2183008

```
# cd /var/lib/mysql
# mkdir bak
# mv ibdata1 bak/
# mv ib_logfile* bak/
# cp -a bak/ibdata1 ibdata1
# cp -a bak/ib_logfile* .
# rm -rf bak
# service mysqld restart
```

That fixed the errors when launching and now phpmyadmin loads fine now.

Answer (score -1):

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=839923

Hi, this is what I did to "fix" the problem locally.

cd /usr/share/php
mv php-gettext php-gettext.orig
ln -s php-php-gettext php-gettext

symbolic linking within the original php-gettext/gettext.inc doesn't
work and generates the error, but linking directory to directory does
work. Of course, it will break things once the problem is fixed
formally, so before updating you may want to reverse those changes.

Additionally this was also in my /var/log/apache2/error.log:

Comment: *"Additionally this was also in my /var/log/apache2/error.log"* - What?