# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql

The problem started after a forced power off..

server is running:

```
ps -ef | grep mysql
mysql     8528     1  0 22:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root      8683  3605  0 22:32 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

netstat doesnt return anything:

`netstat -tulpn | grep 3306`

my.cnf has:

`bind-address            = 127.0.0.1`

error log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13317319/

I would appreciate if someone could help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the status through below command

> mysqladmin -u root -p status

try changing your permission to mysql folder

> chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/

then restart the mysql server

You can even try this if not working yet:

> bind-address = localhost

Comment: Done everything you said.
----
mysqladmin -u root -p status
Enter password: 
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysqld.sock' (111)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysqld.sock' exists!
----
I also touched /tmp/mysqld.sock and changed ownership to mysql

Comment: Locate you mysql.sock this should be as mentioned where mysql folder exist , my.cnf file "socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"

Comment: chmod 777 to that .sock file

Comment: I created mysqld.sock in /var/lib/mysql folder as you said. I chmod it 777 and edited my.cnf and debian.cnf. Nothing changed.

Comment: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.sock' (111)

Comment: I found an answer that worked for me, so I flaged my question as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840743/improper-killing-of-mysqld-now-not-starting/24840903#24840903 Thanks for your time.